# How can I check if there exist any reverse element in list of dict without looping on it

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reverse

My list is like

```
l1 = [ {k1:v1} , {k2:v2}, {v1:k1} ]
```

Is there any better way to check if any dictionary in the list is having reverse pair?

Comment: What do you mean by 'reverse pair'?

Comment: @Omnifarious it means key as value and value as key
@Siperd currently I'm looping over it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116249/how-can-i-check-if-there-exist-any-reverse-element-in-list-of-dict-without-loopin similar question may help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work without loop:

```
k1 = 'k1'
k2 = 'k2'
v1 = 'v1'
v2 = 'v2'
l1 = [ {k1:v1} , {k2:v2}, {v1:k1} ]

kv = [e.items()[0] for e in l1]
print(kv)

vk = [(v, k) for (k, v) in kv]
print(vk)

result = [(k, v) for (k, v) in kv if (k, v) in vk]
print(result)
```

Comment: I would suggest vk = set((v, k) for (k, v) in kv) to avoid an O(n^2) complexity

Comment: yess it worked I used like this,                                                  



result = [(k, v) for (k, v) in kv if (v, k) in kv and k!=v]

Comment: list comprehension is a loop.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to transform the dictionaries in tuple and put the tuple in a set. And look in the set if the reverse tuple is in the set. That would have a complexity of O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Comment: Whoops, sorry for my earlier (deleted) comment, I misunderstood the question. +1

Comment: If you just want to know whether a reverse pair exists or not, then you can test it with `len(d) != len(set([frozenset(i) for i in d.items()]))`. I think this is what Xavier is suggesting.